# Public Dataview from Extension is not visible in Standard Acumatica Screen

Tags: acumatica

Acumatica Business Account screen (CR303000) already has Opportunities Tab.
This tab has only showing the opportunity details, but I want to show opportunity lines details, so new PXSelect written on BusinessAccountMaint_Extension
but this public view not showing in the Acumatica project customization screen as well as visual studio screen definition (CR303000.aspx). Any help regarding this will be much appreciated

[Screen shot of Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXrFt.png)

Comment: [This link may be helpful for you](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Please try and focus on writing a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could try either a Restart Application (System > Management > Process > Apply Updates : Restart Application button) or an iisreset to make sure the UI picks up the latest changes made to your DAC and Graph.

If it didn't work, you can try using the Edit ASPX button under the Action Menu  Button on the Screen editor. There, you can set your data view on the correct DataMember attribute.

Or you can use your view using the Customization Project UI, you could use your Public View on a new TabItem on the CR303030 screen, you could:

Add your public view to your Graph Extension, Save and Publish.

Then after publishing changes, you could go to Screens sections,
Select/Add CR303030 screen.
Add the tabItem to the correct container. 
Add Grid to tabItem container. (see image)
Then you can set the Datamember for your grid by **typing in your Public View.** (See image)

[Set Datamember for correct container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bso20.png)

Then Save and Publish.

After, you could Add Data Fields, select the desired fields.
Create Controls for them, Save and Publish.

[Add Data Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWOFR.png)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help 
i fixed it by manually adding <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="<ViewName>"> in the ASPX page.Seems its a glitch of customization manager (It adds Data member in different place ) .your second suggestion is the answer. So I'am accepting your answer 
Thanks again